# ons-tabbarでページを切り替えたときの処理について

Tags: monaca

ons-tabbarでタブバーを実装を以下のように組んだとき

```
<ons-tabbar var="tabbar" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ons-tabbar-item
            var="tab1"
            icon="home"
            label="売上"
            page="page1.html"
            active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="heart"
            label="お客様一覧"
            page="page2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="star"
            label="ランキング"
            page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="gear"
            label="設定"
            page="page4.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>
```

たとえば、「お客様一覧」を選択し、page2.htmlを表示したときにDBを読み込んでその内容を表示させたい場合どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

page2.htmlにJavaScriptで処理を行っているのですが、実際は処理は行われていません。
readyで処理を実行するよう組んでいるのですが、それでも処理が行われません。
（すでに読み込まれていることになっている？）

ng-controller="MainCtrl"でもやってみましたが、初回起動時しか行われず、想定とは異なる処理になっています。

Answer (score 1):

`ons-tabbar`に`prechange` `postchange`といったイベントがあるので、
その辺で処理を書けば想定している動きが実現できると思います。

詳細は[こちら（リファレンス）](http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html#events-summary)をご参照ください

```js
ons.bootstrap();

function fadeout() {
  $("#modal").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    modal.hide();
  });
}

ons.ready(function() {
  // タブが変わる前
  tab.on('prechange', function(event) {
    $('#page').text(event.tabItem.label);
    modal.show();
  });
  // タブが変わった後
  tab.on('postchange', function(event) {
    var page = event.tabItem.label;
    $('.content').text(page + ' Page Contents');
    setTimeout('fadeout()', 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ons-tabbar var="tab">
  <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="comments.html" label="Comments" icon="ion-chatbox-working"></ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="tags.html" label="Tags" icon="ion-ios-pricetag"></ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html" label="Settings" icon="ion-ios-cog"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Home</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 50px; color: #999; text-align: center" class="content"></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="comments.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Comments</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 50px; color: #999; text-align: center" class="content"></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="tags.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Tags</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 50px; color: #999; text-align: center" class="content"></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Settings</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 50px; color: #999; text-align: center" class="content"></p>
</ons-template>

<ons-modal var="modal" id="modal">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
  <br><br>
  Loading <span id='page'></span> Page.
  <br><br>
  Please wait.
</ons-modal>
```